# Why use Vagrant

Tags: virtual-machine

Thought this would be the best place to put this, but having a debate with someone at work about using vagrant for projects, and aside from having a dedicated setup for all projects that matches our production enviroment I couldn't think of any other reason to not use LAMP/WAMP/MAMP.

If anyone could give me a list of reasons why to use vagrant over a stack it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Vagrant and LAMP/WAMP/MAMP are not mutually exclusive, so it's not a one versus the other comparison

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site is recommending software meeting requirements you name. It's not about telling you what makes product X great, better than product Y, etc.

Comment: ah sorry izzy, wasn't sure where to post, nice one anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the options are not exclusive one of the major benefits of using Vagrant Up is that the "recipe" file that defines the base OS and all of the required options, settings, etc., is a **plain text** file that can be version controlled.  So rather than storing and exchanging huge monolithic image files you have a central repository or share of the base components and the recipe files define how to use them - these are then stored locally in box files to allow fast start up, etc.

The recipe files can also be used as an input to generate the test and production images in the other tools such as packer.